# compute all n-th closest points of all points in a dataset

Tags: python, sorting, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

I have dataset of 1000 points on a plane. I represented all the possible pairs of points in P and calculated the distances of all possible pairs.
What I have to do is: For a given n, calculate all the n-th nearest points for all points p in P.

What I did before:

```
P_pairs = [((33, 9), (34, 13)), ((33, 9), (62, 119)), ((33, 9), (33, 7)), ((33, 9), (48, 123)), ...]

listofdistances =  [{'((33, 9), (34, 13))': 4.123105625617661}, {'((33, 9), (62, 119))': 113.75851616472501}, {'((33, 9), (33, 7))': 2.0}, ...]
```

In this context, I am stuck in sorting `listofdistances` such that for every point, there are the minimum n distances as values left.

Maybe I have to calculate the n-th nearest points directly, instead of calculating all the distances of the points. But I don't exactly know how.

Comment: `P` seems to have a list of all the point pairings. Wasn't it supposed to be `[(33, 9), (34, 13), (62, 119), ...]` with length 1000 instead?

Comment: @Reti43 yes, that's true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
P = [(33, 9), (34, 13), (62, 119), (33, 7), (48, 123)]
P = np.array(P)

x, y = P[:,0], P[:,1]
# Create a distance table of point (row) vs point (column)
dist = np.sqrt((x - x[:,None])**2 + (y - y[:,None])**2)
# The diagonals are 0, as the distance of a point to itself is 0,
# but we want that to have a large value so it comes last in sorting
np.fill_diagonal(dist, np.inf)
# Get the sorted index for each row
idx = dist.argsort(axis=1)
```

Now if you want the nth nearest neighbours, with n = 3, you get that with `idx = idx[:,:3]`. And for the first point you can now do

```
P[0]             # the point itself
P[idx[0]]        # its nearest neighbours
dist[0,idx[0]]   # their distances
```

Comment: thank you mate, that helped me a lot to get an understanding of what's possible with numpy

Answer (score 1):

Creating a list of all possible pairs and then a list of single key dictionaries with distances as values does create a sorting headache. I would instead vectorize this job and use numpy.

```py
import numpy as np

P = np.array([(33, 9), (34, 13), (62, 119), ...])

# Finds the n closest points to p in P
def n_closest_points(p, P, n)
    p_vector = np.tile(p, (len(P), 1))
    dists = np.linalg.norm(P-p_vector, axis=1)
    sorted_dists = np.sort(dists)

    # Exclude the 0th element as the distance from p to itself is 0
    return sorted_dists[1:n+1]
```

Comment: I didn't use numpy...thanks! So you'd suggest, that I run that function for all p?

Comment: If you need to get the `n` closest points for each `p` in `P`, yes. Just run that function `for p in P`.